# My app is crashing when I am implementing both username/password & Google sign in

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**SignUpActivity.kt**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = "YOUR-TAG-NAME"
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient : GoogleSignInClient

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("My_token")
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        val startForResult =  registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                try {
                    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                    signInWithGoogle(account!!)
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
                }
            }
        }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.gSignInBtn).setOnClickListener{
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startForResult.launch(signInIntent)
    }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.usernameSignInButton).setOnClickListener {
        val email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username).text.toString()
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password).text.toString()
        signInWithEmailPassword(email, password)
    }
}

fun signInWithGoogle(googleSignInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.idToken, null)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val user = auth.currentUser
            val hasEmailPasswordAccount = user?.providerData?.any { it.providerId == EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID }
            if (hasEmailPasswordAccount == true) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                Log.w("Login", "User has an email/password account")
            } else {
                if (task.result?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser == true) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java))
                } else {
                    val role = user?.displayName
                    if (role == "buyer") {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, BuyerActivity::class.java))
                    } else if (role == "seller") {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, SellerActivity::class.java))
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("Login", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
        }
    }
}

fun signInWithEmailPassword(email: String, password: String) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val user = auth.currentUser
            val hasGoogleAccount = user?.providerData?.any { it.providerId == GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID }
            if (hasGoogleAccount == true) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                Log.w("Login", "User has a Google account")
            } else {
                if (task.result?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser == true) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java))
                } else {
                    val role = user?.displayName
                    if (role == "buyer") {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, BuyerActivity::class.java))
                    } else if (role == "seller") {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, SellerActivity::class.java))
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("Login", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Build.Gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.shoppo"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.shoppo"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0")

implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2")
implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
annotationProcessor("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

**My Error**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shoppo, PID: 25224
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoppo/com.example.shoppo.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3900)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4046)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2440)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8321)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:581)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
at com.example.shoppo.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.kt:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8547)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1437)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3881)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4046) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8321) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:581) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)

I am trying to implement both username/password & Google SignIn. If someone is already registered from Google, he will not be able to register via username/password and vice versa. If the user is in for first time logging in so he will be redirected to the registration page. If he is already in the database, he will be redirected to the respective section of buyer or seller. But I am not able to understand what went wrong.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: I just included the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button at

Most likely because of the following line of code:

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.gSignInBtn).setOnClickListener{/*.../*}
```

And that's because, inside your XML file, you have added a view of type [SignInButton](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton) while in your code you're trying to use (cast) it to a [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button), hence the error. Please note that such an operation is not possible because, between these two classes, there is no inheritance relationship. To solve this, you have to find the view and set the generic type to `SignInButton`:

```
findViewById<SignInButton>(R.id.gSignInBtn).setOnClickListener{/*.../*}
//
```